# How to pass two objects to a view

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

How can I pass two objects to codeigniter view page ?

Is this possible ?

```
$this->load->view('myView', $object1, $object2);
```

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, passing multiple objects as parameter is poosible but I am afraid the syntax you mentioned above is not correct.

Try:

```
$data['object1'] = $object1; 
$data['object2'] = $object2;
$this->load->view('myView', $data);
```

And on the view page access it as `$object1` and `$object2`

Adding **Dynamic Data** to the View
Data is passed from the controller to the view by way of an array or an object in the second parameter of the view loading function. Here is an example using an array:

```
$data = array(
               'title' => 'My Title',
               'heading' => 'My Heading',
               'message' => 'My Message'
          );

$this->load->view('blogview', $data);
```

And here's an example using an object:

```
$data = new Someclass();
$this->load->view('blogview', $data);
```

[Views:CodeIgniter User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)